# controlling the number of chatroom users in xmpp server

Tags: java, plugins, components, xmpp, openfire

Am   working   on   the   design   of   a   real   time   chat   engine   using   xmpp server   such   as   openfire,  i   want to  be   able   to limit   the number   of users   that   can   enter   a chat   room,  'programming room' should have only 30 people in the room the next person to enter the room, thats from 31st person up should be assigned to 'programming room-2' which will be automatically created once the number of users reaches 30, also as soon as users in programming room1 drops below 30 new users that enters programming room should be assigned to programming room1. Should i use plugin/component to achieve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of going to hell, as suggested in your comment above, I'll provide you an approach.

Create a server-side component.  Your client sends it some protocol (such as [XEP-0050](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0050.html)) and the service sends your client an invite to the correct room.  If you want existing clients to be able to join, also accept a plain text message.

The component will need to join each room to keep track of the number of participants using their presence.  As such, just have the component create each room as needed, before inviting any participants.